# Как создать список с добавлением элементов в него в одну строку?

Tags: python, list, список

Мне нужно создать список данных в одну строку и я не помню как именно
помню только что начинается так:

```
s = [input()....]
```

еще помню, что там есть `for()`

можно сказать, что эта строка по функции заменяет следующий код:

```
n = int(input())
a = []
for i in range(n):
    slova = input()
    a.append(slova)
```

Comment: `s = [input() for i in  range(5)]`

Comment: @S.Nick да,что-то такое, но в вашем примере почему то при любом значении первого ввода, количество элементов списка всегда 4, а нужно чтобы количество элементов списка потом запрашивалось у пользователя ровно столько, какое число он ввел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если вам надо получить список целых чисел, введя их через пробел, то

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split())
```

если вам надо получить список `n` строк, то

```
arr = [input() for _ in range(n)]
```

а если `n` тоже надо получить от пользователя, то

```
arr = [input() for _ in range(int(input()))]
```

вместо `for` можно использовать `map`, но получается более извращённо:

```
arr = list(map(lambda i: input(), range(int(input()))))
```

можно и так:

```
arr = list(map(input, range(int(input()))))
```

но тогда будет на экране выводиться номер от `0` до `n - 1` перед вводом каждой строки

Comment: да, точно , 3 вариант решения  подходит

Comment: кинул еще 2 варианта - но это уже извратец :)